# Illegal invocation using SQLite in web

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

```
import { SQLite } from 'expo-sqlite';
export const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");
```

I tried to use sqlite in the expo and run from a browser, However, I get error TypeError: Illegal invocation, any can help me please

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL API is so bad it was ultimately abandoned as a standard for the web.

The expo-sqlite module provides an SQL database with a WebSQL based interface. This is pretty powerful, and supports pretty much all the features of SQLite. SQLite is also perfect for exactly the kind of use case that apps with offline requirements have. It lets you store large amounts of structured data on disk and read only the parts you need for displaying the current screen into memory.

Maybe you should try `@databases/expo`
https://itnext.io/using-sqlite-in-expo-for-offline-react-native-apps-a408d30458c3

```js
import connect, {sql} from '@databases/expo';

const db = connect('my-database');
```